# How do I return a specific type of tuple in F#?

Tags: f#

This is the code that I am working on:

```
// RopResult
type RopResult<'TSuccess, 'TMessage> =
    | Success of 'TSuccess * 'TMessage list
    | Failure of 'TMessage list

// result to return
type ResultForClient<'TSuccessObj, 'TMessages> =
    bool * 'TSuccessObj * seq<'TMessages>

// return the above type
let resultToClient =
    function 
    | Success (x, msg) -> true, x, Seq.ofList msg
    | Failure errors -> false, Object(), Seq.ofList errors
```

The `resultToClient` function appears to just return a tuple opposed to the specific tuple type of `ResultForClient`.  What am I missing here?  On a side note, am I representing the `RopResult` type correctly in the return.  As you can see the `RopResult` is generic so in case of failure I insert `Object()`. Does this seem correct?

Comment: it does not appear because `ResultForClient` is just a Synonym and Kevin gave you an workaround. For the failure case: this seems to be a smell IMO - if you don't always need the `'TSuccessObj` make this part of the tuple `optional` (or use `RopResult` ... kindof strange that you did not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the return type:

```
let resultToClient v : ResultForClient<_,_> =
  match v with 
  | Success (x, msg) -> true, x, Seq.ofList msg
  | Failure errors -> false, Object(), Seq.ofList errors
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to do [Railway Oriented Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/).

> am I representing the RopResult type correctly in the return. As you can see the RopResult is generic so in case of failure I insert Object(). Does this seem correct?

No, that doesn't seem to be correct. By using `Object()`, the inferred type of `resultToClient` is

```
RopResult<System.Object,'a> -> ResultForClient<System.Object,'a>
```

Since `ResultForClient` is only a type alias, this is equivalent to

```
RopResult<Object,'a> -> bool * Object * seq<'a>
```

That is, the return value of the function is `bool * Object * seq<'a>`. This looks more like a nasty combination of return codes and untyped data than a Fucntional data type. Is that what you had in mind? What do you intend to do with the `Object`?

---

The point of Railway Oriented Programming is that the `RopResult` data type itself carries information about the result of any computation (whether or not it failed), so unless you're trying to interop with some other system that doesn't understand sum types (Discriminated Unions), you'll only be throwing away information by attempting to 'unwrap' the `RopResult`.

Comment: Yes that's the idea, but maybe I'm on the wrong thought path.  I am trying to create a utility function that will make types available in C#.  I assume that C# can't interpret Discriminated Unions as in the Success and Failure cases for the Railway result, so I figured that maybe I could transfer the results to a tuple that C# could easily interop with.  What is the suggested way in handling this matter?

Comment: In Object-Oriented Programming on .NET, the recommended way to 'return' errors is to throw exceptions... Not as nice, but that's basically what you have to work with.